# Why does np.array**3 lead to a different solution than (np.array/1)**3 in my code?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this code to calculate the integral in time of:
Q =  (Q_max*(1 - (time/t_0 - 1)**2))
which I derived analytically.

```
import numpy as np
Q_max       = 400                   # W m-2
t_0         = 6*3600                # seconds
dt          = 60                    # seconds
time        = np.arange(0,2*t_0,dt) 
Q_integral_A = Q_max*((time)**2/(t_0) - (time)**3/(3*(t_0)**2))
```

However, I found that Q_integral_A gives the wrong solution. After trying a lot of stuff, I found out that doing the following leads to the right solution (dividing the second "time" by 1):

```
Q_integral_B = Q_max*((time)**2/(t_0) - (time/1)**3/(3*(t_0)**2))
```

What is happening here? Why is there a difference between Q_integral_A and Q_integral_B?

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDsS9.png)

Versions used:
Python 3.8.5
Numpy 1.20.3
Spyder 4.2.5

Comment: I get the same result: `np.allclose(Q_integral_A, Q_integral_B)` -> `True`

Comment: Thanks for trying! This makes it even weirder... I get `False` using your method.

Comment: Provide all details of the versions you are using. Also confirm that you get `False` with your dummy example.

Comment: Python version 3.8.5 and Spyder 4.2.5

Comment: Most importantly, `numpy.__version__`

Comment: Numpy version 1.20.3

Comment: I don't know what to say, if the toy example is giving you the error try to update, if you still have it there might be a hardware related issue (do you have a Mac?)

Comment: @mozway the issue is that in Windows, `long` will be 32 bits but in *nix, it will be 64 bits. The problem is that the default int size in numpy is whatever the `long` size is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into problem myself, and I get the same result. So at first `time` is a int32, but when you do `time / 1` it becomes float64. It shouldn't bring problems by itself, but `time` contains some big numbers, and raising them to 3rd power results in overflowing ([here's what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB1NJ.png)), but it doesn't effect float, because it works in different way.

To solve it just pass `dtype="int64"` `time = np.arange(0, 2*t_0, dt, dtype = "int64")`, but it won't solve the problem for even larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is going on is that you are on Windows so:

```
time = np.arange(0,2*t_0,dt)
```

Defaults to `dtype=np.int32`, then the `/` operator results in promotion to `np.float64`.

I can reproduce your error if I use

```
time = np.arange(0,2*t_0,dt, dtype=np.int32)
```

And I bet it would be fixed for you if you use:

```
time = np.arange(0,2*t_0,dt, dtype=np.int64)
```

In general, you should be explicit with `dtypes`. If only to get more reproducible behavior.